# xamarin: Get menu item for MasterDetailPage

Tags: menu, xamarin

On the top left I get a back icon, but I would like to have a menu icon there.

I am working with xamarin forms and I am using a MasterDetailPage for my menu.

[image]

This is my code:

```
 static MasterDetailPage MDPage;

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        MDPage = new MasterDetailPage {
            Master = new ContentPage {
                Title = "Master",
                Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null,
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    Children = { MenuLink("A"), MenuLink("B"), MenuLink("C") }
                },
            },
            Detail = new NavigationPage(CreateContentPage("A")),
        };
        MDPage.IsPresentedChanged += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + MDPage.IsPresented);
        return MDPage;
    }

    static Button MenuLink(string name)
    {
        return new Button {
            Text = name,
            Command = new Command(o => {
                MDPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(CreateContentPage(name));
                MDPage.IsPresented = false;
            }),
        };
    }

    static Button Link(string name)
    {
        return new Button {
            Text = name,
            Command = new Command(o => MDPage.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(CreateContentPage(name))),
        };
    }

    static ContentPage CreateContentPage(string text)
    {
        return new ContentPage { Title = text, Content = Link(text + ".sub") };
    }
}
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a menu icon for iOS, but not Android - you need to specify one for both platforms, or just use the same icon for both

```
Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null,
```

to hide the Android app icon, do this in your `MainActivity`'s `FinishedLaunching`

```
// hide app icon in Android action/nav bar
ActionBar.SetIcon(app_name.Resource.Color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

customize your app theme in android. You have to change in style.xml for removing app icon.